# Unable to delete a document from cosmos using DocumentClient in java

Tags: spring-boot, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

Trying to delete a doc based on the Id in cosmosdb from Java(SpringBoot) Azure function using DocumentClient

The key and uri used are absolutely correct

```
DocumentClient client = new DocumentClient(cosmosDBUri, cosmosDBKey, null, null);
         try {
                String documentLink = String.format("/dbs/%s/colls/%s/docs/%s", "db1", "col1", "newId");
                context.getLogger().info("documentLink: " + documentLink);
                client.deleteCollection(documentLink, null);
            } catch (Exception e) {
```

> The input authorization token can't serve the request. Please check
>   that the expected payload is built as per the protocol, and check the
>   key being used. Server used the following payload to sign: 'delete
>   docs dbs/db1/colls/col1/docs/newId thu, 29 aug 2019 13:40:44 gmt
>
> ' ActivityId: *********************,
>   Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.5.1, StatusCode: Unauthorized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `deleteCollection` when you should be using [`deleteDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.documentdb.documentclient.deletedocument?view=azure-java-stable#com_microsoft_azure_documentdb_DocumentClient_deleteDocument_String_RequestOptions_).

In addition, double check that you are not using a read-only key.

Comment: I had correct key, one more thing that I have noticed is we cannot give second parameter to deleteCollections as null. We have to pass the partition key set in RequestsOptions